# Android: Unresolved packages, even if I have modified the value of the attribute `package` of the manifest

Tags: android

In the manifest of my Android app, I have written:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="logic">
```

According to the documentation (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro), all the classes in the manifest will be resolved under the directory `logic`. So, given the below directories tree, why, in this manifest, does this line...:

`<activity android:name="bundles.splash_screen.controllers.SplashScreen">`

...raise the errors "**Unresolved package bundles ; Unresolved package splash_screen ; Unresolved[...]"**?

**The directories tree is:**

- app

  - src

    - main

      - logic

        - bundles

          - splash_screen
                 - controllers
                               - SplashScreen.java

I have carefully taken in account this tree and specified the correct package in the attribute `package`, and it can't resolve the classes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Android Studio, the default source directory is

> src/main/java/

Package declared in `AndroidManifest.xml` refers to the folder structure under Java package.

[image: android package tree]

Have you modified your project configuration to change the default source directory?

If not, i think you are missing the Java folder.

Reference: https://developer.android.com/studio/projects

Comment: I've edited this directory name "java" to "logic" indeed, because  I got an error like "'java' is not a valid package name". I think I misunderstood this error. But, I'm curious: is it possible to keep my "logic" name active, and tell Android Studio that "java" directory is now named "logic"? I didn't find the configuration option for this in the menu "Project structure".

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28657879/refreshing-gradle-in-intellij-causes-source-folder-structure-to-change is the answer to my comment